# JavaScript - Checking if all values in an array are not Null - Array / Each /

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, null

Working on TicTacToe in JavaScript/JQuery. Beginner programmer but couldn't find this online.

At the moment I have a normal array called "game_board". The array has 9 values which are 0-8. It is not a 'hash'.

I'm looking into a loop or similar that checks if all values in array are not null. Should all values in the "game_board" array not be Null then the code should make an action such as [Alert("Draw")]. If any values in the array have a value the function should do nothing.

Here's my code attempt. Any ideas would be aweesome. My attempt is the theory that the loop breaks if it finds a null value. If it does not find a null value it goes to ELSE and reports 'draw'

```
    // check draw
for (var p = 0; p < 9; p++) { 
    if (game_board[p] === null) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        alert("Draw");
    }
}
```

Thanks very much. I know this maybe a basic question but appreciate any answers.

Please excuse my newness! Not 100% sure of the logic. Perhaps something with Jquery will help!

Comment: Do you want the alert to happen only if *none* of the items in the list are null?

Comment: Yes thanks :). Imagine TicTacToe with 9 squares filled in with no winner :P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the values are `null`:

```
var isAtLeastOneNull = game_board.some(function(i) { return i === null; });
```

Alternatively, use [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to do the reverse check:

```
var areAllNotNull = game_board.every(function(i) { return i !== null; });
```

Demo:

```js
var game_board = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null, true];

document.writeln('There is at least one null item: ' + game_board.some(function(i) { return i === null; }));
document.writeln('<br />');

game_board = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true];

document.writeln('There is at least one null item: ' + game_board.some(function(i) { return i === null; }));
```

Comment: This sounds awesome. I'm just trying to get it to work!

Comment: I think I must be a goldfish. Or maybe it's too late! Is this how I'd do your solution?                                                                                                  var isAtLeastOneNull = game_board.some(function(p) { return p === null; });
 if (isAtLeastOneNull = false) {
  alert("draw")
 }

Comment: That's close - just change `(isAtLeastOneNull = false)` to `(isAtLeastOneNull === false)`. Or even better, `(!isAtLeastOneNull) `.

Comment: // check draw
 if (game_board.some(elem => elem === null)) {
 }
 else {
  alert("draw");
 } // HUZZAHHH!!

Comment: Haha tiny bug but I can fix :P. Now even if you win on the last move it's a draw :P. I'm sure I can fix though lol

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for this solution.